# How to gather information about bluetooth encryption methods from Android scan?

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, bluetooth

Afaik, there are three distinct encryption methods, used throughout Bluetooth devices: E0 (used everywhere, but not advised from Bluetooth version 4.2), SAFER+ (used in Bluetooth BR/EDR till 2.1 version) and AES-CCM (in BLE, from Bluetooth version 4.0).

One important requirement, is that devices cannot be paired or connected. I wonder, if there is some way, to gather info about remote Bluetooth device encryption method, using Kotlin app. I didn't found anything in BluetoothDevice class through Broadcast Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

The idea in Bluetooth is not to "get the current encryption level". Instead you request a certain security level when you perform a particular "service request". The Bluetooth stack will then do whatever it takes (for example perform a pairing attempt or initiate encryption using a key in the bond store).

For example, on Android you have https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createInsecureL2capChannel(int) for starting an L2CAP CoC having level 1 and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createL2capChannel(int) for starting an L2CAP CoC having level 3.

You can read more about this in the Bluetooth Core Specification, Vol 3: Host, GAP section 10.3 for BLE and section 5 (BR/EDR).

A BLE device does not advertise (before connecting) whether it supports encryption or not. I'm not sure about BR/EDR.